# "Simpler" proof of general Nullstellensatz for Jacobson rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

*Assume all rings/algebras are commutative with identity. "$\hookrightarrow$" means injection and "$\twoheadrightarrow$" means surjection. $A_f$ is the localization of $A$ on the point $f$. We slightly abuse $\mathfrak p\cap R$ to denote the retraction $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ of the prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset S$ in the ring map $f:R\to S$*.

*$A$ is a **Jacobson ring** if every prime ideal is the intersection of the maximal ideals containing it.*

---

The word "Simple" refers to that we can apply the [standard techniques](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FV) (see "Proof of $(\color{RoyalBlue}2)$") used to prove the Nullstellensatz for fields. The key is to prove $\operatorname{Im} (A/\mathfrak p\to (A/\mathfrak p)_f/\mathfrak m)$ is a field and construct a maximal ideal as $\ker (A/\mathfrak p\to (A/\mathfrak p)_f/\mathfrak m)$ in $A/\mathfrak p$ in the arrow compositions below: $$k\to A/\mathfrak p\hookrightarrow (A/\mathfrak p)_f\twoheadrightarrow (A/\mathfrak p)_f/\mathfrak m$$

Here is the form of Nullstellensatz I would like to prove

> If $R$ is a Jacobson ring, then so is any finite generated $R$-algebra $A$.

**Here is my proof:** Assume $A$ is not Jacobson and choose a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ and an element $f$ such that $f\notin \mathfrak p$ but $f$ is contained in all maximal ideals containing $\mathfrak p$. We have composition arrows $$R/(\mathfrak p\cap R)\to A/\mathfrak p\hookrightarrow (A/\mathfrak p)_f\twoheadrightarrow(A/\mathfrak p)_f/\mathfrak m_{\mathfrak p}$$ where $\mathfrak m_{\mathfrak p}$ is a maximal ideal of $(A/\mathfrak p)_f$. Inspired by the classic Nullstellensatz for fields, we will need $\mathfrak p\cap R$ to be large enough to make $R/(\mathfrak p\cap R)$ a field. To be precise, we make a hypothesis and assume it is true.

> **Hypothesis.** There is a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\supset \mathfrak p$ such that $f\notin \mathfrak q$ and $\mathfrak q\cap R$ is maximal in $R$.

Then looking at the composition arrows again for $\mathfrak q$: $$R/(\mathfrak q\cap R)\to A/\mathfrak q\hookrightarrow (A/\mathfrak q)_f\twoheadrightarrow(A/\mathfrak q)_f/\mathfrak m_{\mathfrak q}$$

$(A/\mathfrak q)_f/\mathfrak m$ is a finite field extension of the field $R/(\mathfrak q\cap R)$. As an intermediate extension, the image of $A/\mathfrak q$ in $(A/\mathfrak q)_f/\mathfrak m$ is also finite over $R/(\mathfrak q\cap R)$, and must then be a field. Thus $\ker(A/\mathfrak q\to (A/\mathfrak q)_f/\mathfrak m)$ is a maximal ideal in $A/\mathfrak q$, and corresponds to a maximal ideal in $A$ containing $\mathfrak p$ but not containing $f$, contradiction.

The hypothesis is true, for example [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034J) gives a sharper result, showing $(A/\mathfrak q)_f$ is a field. And then use the fact that $R/(\mathfrak q\cap R)\hookrightarrow (A/\mathfrak q)_f$ is a finite type extension from a Jacobson ring to a field to deduce $R/(\mathfrak q\cap R)$ is a field, as shown [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CY7).

Is there a easier way through to prove the hypothesis above without showing $(A/\mathfrak q)_f$ is a field, but rather studying the prime/maximal correspondence between $R\to A$?

---

**Update:** I am looking at a particularly interesting result which will prove our hypothesis:

> If $R$ is Jacobson, then for any finite type ring map $f: R\to A$, $f^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$ is maximal in $R$ if $\mathfrak m$ is maximal in $A$.

To prove our hypothesis using this result, form the composition ring map $R\to A\to (A/\mathfrak p)_f$, choose a maximal ideal of $(A/\mathfrak p)_f$ and look at the corresponding prime ideal in $A$ and in $R$.

**Update:** The [converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659783/inverse-image-of-maximal-ideals-under-finite-type-ring-maps) of the result is also true, and strongly relies on [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034J) result. I believe that is why stacks project uses the sharper result to prove the Nullstellensatz for Jacobson rings.

> $R$ is Jacobson if and only if for any finite type ring map $R\to A$, inverse image of maximal ideals are maximal as well.

Comment: The "particularly interesting" property at the end is certainly true, cf. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GB but I don't see a "simple" proof right now...